# Modifying post-2040 macOS file creation/modification dates

Tags: macos, unix-timestamp, nfs, afp

In my Synology NAS, I have an APFS share with files that have been transferred back and forth for decades across different OSes.

- original systems: probably ext4 filesystem and Synology-hosted NFS mount, years ago (various systems, Linux/Windows)
- current system: EXT4 filesystem, with Synology-hosted AFP mounts (to a macOS 10.15 system, though I doubt that matters)

For files that were copied via NFS originally, and now hosted via AFP, all the file dates seem to be offset by some amount. I can sort of eyeball the datetime offset, but **is there a definitive number I can use**? (And a simple way to parse/modify the times using something like `GetFileInfo`?)

- For reference, I have a copy of iTerm2-3_2_6.zip, dated "2039-01-22 08:25:17". I would probably map that to 2019-01-21 (release date for 3.2.7), implying a 20-year offset.
- The closest thing I can think of is macOS epoch starting on 2001-01-01 instead of UNIX 1970-01-01, but that's a *30*-year offset.
- There's also the "[year 2038 problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252542/is-any-version-of-os-x-macos-vulnerable-to-the-year-2038-problem)", and some software might be doing something clever with 32-bit overflows to support post-2038 datetimes, but I have at least one file dated "2031-08-10", so that seems unlikely.

Comment: On further investigation, this includes "original systems" as late as 2021. This could be due to an EXT2/3-EXT4 migration changing what timestamp data is stored, https://www.sans.org/blog/understanding-ext4-part-2-timestamps/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something related to 32-bit and 64-bit overflows, somewhere in this complicated storage stack; the way the datetimes + error offsets add up is consistently close to 2^31, though I wasn't able to find any clear pattern.

Also, I noticed strange behavior from my Synology system's use of eCryptFS, which seems to lag metadata updates when done in batch. (In particular, I suspect that some eCryptFS/Synology metadata is getting translated incorrectly, or just never written to disk.)

---

Anyway, I basically wrote a Python script that does the following:

- check if os.stat() reports an atime/mtime newer than 2030
- check that both atime and mtime are newer; error out if they differ
- adjust both times back by 632599096 seconds (offset based on comparing copies of the one file I found in common between two systems).

with the following caveats to watch out for:

- macOS's `GetFileInfo`/`SetFile` utilities only support 32-bit datetimes, so you should generally avoid using them (even just to verify the metadata updates).
- something in the Synology/eCryptFS encryption gets very slow, so after a few dozen metadata updates, the updates will no longer be visible (even after calling `sync` from the shell). But if you give it some time, you'll see the corrected atime/mtime changes.
- The OS-specific `os.stat` field, `ctime`, does literally track metadata update times. And there doesn't seem to be a way to manually set it (nor a need to, since this isn't visible through any GUI).

The combination of slow metadata updates + `GetFileInfo` reporting the wrong time made this incredibly frustrating, until I figured both out. In practice, this means you have to test metadata updates on a few files at a time, then your large batch execution can only be verified a few hours later (I waited a day).

This should have been a blog post, good riddance.